# I can't connect to AWS EC2 Windows Instance from WinSCP (local laptop machine)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012, winscp

I used the same security group and ACLs for the Amazon Linux instance, and it worked. I then added a 22 port number to the firewall of the Windows server, but again it failed. I then turned off the complete firewall, but this again did not work.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows servers don't accept SSH connections by default. WinSCP works over SSH, which Linux supports by default, but Windows servers do not. WinSCP is basically an application intended to run on a Windows client machine, to copy files to a Linux server machine. If you want to be able to send files over SSH to your Windows server, you will have to install SSH server software on that Windows server.

Comment: Nice information. I have seen a few youtube videos following just basic steps and yet they connected to AWS EC2 Windows.

Comment: If you are saying I am incorrect in my statement, then please link to the video or other information you have. Looking at the WinSCP website, it says it supports SFTP, SSH, S3, and WebDAV protocols. None of those protocols are enabled by default on a Windows server.

Comment: no dear. I am not saying this. Actually, I couldn't recall it clearly. May be you are 100% correct.

Comment: Can you recommend any solution on how can I copy the file to the windows server from my laptop?

Comment: Windows Remote Desktop allows you to copy from one computer, and paste into the other. If this is just a one time thing I would use that. If this is a really big file, I would use an S3 bucket as an intermediary.

Comment: I have installed OpenSSH Server and tried to connect. Boom!!! You are a super hero man!!